# Why does Python thinks 4,110,671 is between 3760 and 6180?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, integer

[The top left is the tab delimited file of my ranges, top right is my file with the list of number I want to sort and their is the code I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94zMw.png) I am trying to use python to sort a big list (2000 integers) of numbers into a corresponding list of ranges.
Both lists are from tab delimited files and I am using an if loop to sort them. 
It works but it's like it's sorting 4110 then 41106 then 411067 then 4110671- I just want it to sort 4110671 why is it recognising it as those other numbers?

Comment: Could you post the code with the issue you're encountering?

Comment: Are you sure they are actually of the type integer, and not a string?

Comment: Most likely it is doing string sorting.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound I have added a photo with what my files look like and my code :)

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Sorry I am VERY new to python what is string sorting?

Comment: @scarlettveronica check this out to see what they're saying about 'sorting string instead of integer' https://repl.it/E0h4/0